# Help Configuring VirtualPC 2007 on Vista Host with XP VM to access Vista WAMP Server

Tags: wampserver, virtual-pc-2007

I have a Vista laptop on which I'm running wampserver.  I have Virtual PC 2007 setup with Windows XP running on the VM.

My goal is to be able to use the XP VM to run IE6 to view web pages on the Vista wampserver. I'm not interested in having the XP VM have any access to the internet -- only to my Vista wampserver.

The vista wampserver works fine.  I've installed the MS loopback adapter, but every time I select it in the XP VM, I get a "network cable unplugged" error.

In any case, I've turned the wampserver to "server online" but I still can't seem to get the virtual XP to see the vista wampserver.

Ideally I'd just go to IE6 in the XP VM and type "localhost" to be able to get to the wampserver that's running on Vista. I've even tried typing in the machine's name, too, but to no avail.

I didn't play with static IPs, because I want this to be able to work regardless of whether or not I have internet access.  So if I'm on the train and I have no wireless connection, I don't want the setup to be limited because the host (vista wampserver) doesn't have an IP. I also did not bridge the connections because I am not clear how that plays a role in all of this.

Thanks so much in advance for any advice.

Comment: post your question on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: why not have VPC2007 run directly from Win7?.. I have it running like that!

Answer (score 0):

did you install VM additions on VPC2007 (vmadditions.iso)?
did you define shared folders within in your VM's .vhc configuration file?
did you install SP1 and hotfix for VPC2007?